# how to pass a test with expect.js async done() taking an error?

Tags: javascript

Mocha website states:

"To make things even easier, the done() callback accepts an error, so we may use this directly: [see their example]"

So lets try that:

```js
it('works',function(done){
  expect(1).to.be(1)
  done( new Error('expected error') )
})
/* Insert the error manually for testing and clarity. */
```

run it and:

```js
1 failing

1) works:
 Error: expected error
  at Context.<anonymous>
  [stack trace]
```

How do we make the test pass when the error response is the desired result?

Comment: I agree, this would be the intuitive way to do it

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That's not async. The callback function is just there for you to inform mocha that you're testing async code and so mocha shouldn't run the next test until you call the callback function. This is an example of how to use the callback function:

```
it('works',function(done){
    setTimeout(function(){
        // happens 0.5 seconds later:
        expect(1).to.be(1);
        done(); // this tells mocha to run the next test
    },500);
});
```

Also, mocha does not handle any form of exceptions, async or otherwise. It leaves that up to an exception library of your choosing. In your case you're using `expect.js`? If so, expect handles expected errors via the `throwException` method (also called `throwError`):

```
it('throws an error',function(done){
    expect(function(){
        throw new Error('expected error');
    }).to.throwError(/expected error/);
});
```

Now, in general async code in node.js don't throw errors. They pass errors to the callback as parameters instead. So to handle async errors you can simply check the err object:

```
// using readFile as an example of async code to be tested:
it('returns an error',function(done){
    fs.readFile(filename, function (err, data) {
        expect(err).to.be.an(Error);
        done(); // tell mocha to run next test
    })
});
```

So use `to.throwError()` if you're checking synchronous errors and `to.be.an(Error)` if you're checking async errors.

---

### Additional notes:

The first time I saw this I was stumped. How can mocha know that the test is synchronous or asynchronous when the only difference is weather the function you pass to it accepts an argument or not? In case you're like me and are scratching your head wondering how, I learned that all functions in javascript have a `length` property that describes how many arguments it accepts in its declaration. No, not the `arguments.length` thing, the function's own `length`. For example:

```
function howManyArguments (fn) {
    console.log(fn.length);
}

function a () {}
function b (x) {}
function c (x,y,z) {}

howManyArguments(a); // logs 0
howManyArguments(b); // logs 1
howManyArguments(c); // logs 3
howManyArguments(howManyArguments); // logs 1
howManyArguments(function(x,y){}); // logs 2
```

So mocha basically checks the function's length to determine weather to treat it as a synchronous function or asynchronous function and pauses execution waiting for the `done()` callback if it's asynchronous.

---

### Even more additional notes:

Mocha, like most other js unit test runners and libraries, work by catching errors. So it expects functions like `expect(foo).to.be.an.integer()` to throw an error if the assertion fails. That's how mocha communicates with assertion libraries like expect or chai.

Now, as I mentioned above, a common idiom in node is that async functions don't throw errors but passes an error object as the first argument. When this happens mocha cannot detect the error and so can't detect a failing test. The work-around to this is that if you pass the error object from the async code to the callback function it will treat it the same as a thrown error.

So, taking one of my examples above:

```
it('executes without errors',function(done){
    fs.readFile(filename, function (err, data) {
        done(err); // if err is undefined or null mocha will treat
                   // it as a pass but if err is an error object
                   // mocha treats it as a fail.
    })
});
```

Or simply:

```
it('executes without errors',function(done){
    fs.readFile(filename,done);
});
```

Strictly speaking, this feature is a bit redundant when used with libraries like expect.js which allows you to manually check the returned error object but it's useful for when your assertion library can't check the error object (or when you don't really care about the result of the async function but just want to know that no errors are thrown).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I guess what I'm still wondering is why the mocha docs bother to explain that done takes an error as an argument.

Comment: This shows how I ended up using async in my tests. http://pastebin.com/C8d02LRm

I decided to ignore the mocha doc comment about done() accepting an error.

Comment: I think what the docs mean is that if you pass an error object to `done` then it will interpret it as an error just like thrown errors. I'll expand my answer..

Comment: @slebetman `done` can be used as a callback for async functions that take a callback. So your last example can be rewritten like so: `fs.readFile(filename, done)`.

Comment: @robertklep: Ah, that's true. I'll add that to my answer. Thanks

Comment: The first example gives a timeout message if the `expect` fails. It does not provide good details of why it failed that `expect` generates.

Answer (score 0):

You can also return your async such as promise as below.

```
it('Test DNA', () => {
    return resolvedPromise.then( (result)=>{
       expect(result).to.equal('He is not a your father.');      
    },(err)=>{
       console.log(err);
    });
});
```